# header footer include in phalcon website without volt

Tags: web, include, footer, phalcon

i am developing a dynamic website using phalcon and i have header and footer for every page in the project so how could i include it throughout my whole project without using volt engine.i don't want to use volt engine because it is very complex to use.

```
/**
 * Read the configuration
 */
$config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/config.ini');

$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        __DIR__ . $config->application->controllersDir,
        __DIR__ . $config->application->pluginsDir,
        __DIR__ . $config->application->libraryDir,
        __DIR__ . $config->application->modelsDir,
    )
)->register();

/**
 * The FactoryDefault Dependency Injector automatically register the right services providing a full stack framework
 */
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

/**
 * We register the events manager
 */
$di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {

    $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

    $security = new Security($di);

    /**
     * We listen for events in the dispatcher using the Security plugin
     */
    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', $security);

    $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $dispatcher;
});

/**
 * The URL component is used to generate all kind of urls in the application
 */
$di->set('url', function() use ($config){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri($config->application->baseUri);
    return $url;
});


$di->set('view', function() use ($config) {

    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();

    $view->setViewsDir(__DIR__ . $config->application->viewsDir);

    $view->registerEngines(array(
        ".volt" => 'volt'
    ));

    return $view;
});

/**
 * Setting up volt
 */
$di->set('volt', function($view, $di) {

    $volt = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $di);

    $volt->setOptions(array(
        "compiledPath" => "../cache/volt/"
    ));

    return $volt;
}, true);

/**
 * Database connection is created based in the parameters defined in the configuration file
 */
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => $config->database->host,
        "username" => $config->database->username,
        "password" => $config->database->password,
        "dbname" => $config->database->name
    ));
});

/**
 * If the configuration specify the use of metadata adapter use it or use memory otherwise
 */
$di->set('modelsMetadata', function() use ($config) {
    if (isset($config->models->metadata)) {
        $metaDataConfig = $config->models->metadata;
        $metadataAdapter = 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\\'.$metaDataConfig->adapter;
        return new $metadataAdapter();
    }
    return new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory();
});

/**
 * Start the session the first time some component request the session service
 */
$di->set('session', function(){
    $session = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});

/**
 * Register the flash service with custom CSS classes
 */
$di->set('flash', function(){
    return new Phalcon\Flash\Direct(array(
        'error' => 'alert alert-error',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ));
});

/**
 * Register a user component
 */
$di->set('elements', function(){
    return new Elements();
});

$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application();
$application->setDI($di);
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Partials](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#using-partials) are one option. They're view logic that you extract out for reuse in many places.

Create and store your header and footer files under the /shared dir and do the following:

```
<div class="top"><?php $this->partial("shared/header") ?></div>

...

<div class="footer"><?php $this->partial("shared/footer") ?></div>
```

Edit: 
Do something like the below:

```
Change the layout to be used instead of using the name of the latest controller name

<?php

$this->view->setLayout('main');
```

More information can be found in the [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html) regarding views.

Comment: so i have to add above code in all the files in whole project, but i want to make it dynamically and call throughout project

Comment: Please see the edit,  hopefully this will point you in the right direction.